# sed substitution with backslash in pattern?

Tags: regex, sed, backslash

The best problem description is given by looking at http://rubular.com/r/9zDHFh0gGc. Why is `sed` not working like that? I think the problem depends on those backslashes `\`in the fragments, for example in `{1+\cos^2 t + t^2}`.
In precise I want to substitute in the source

```
Test Text
= \int_0^{\pi}\vvvec
{1+\cos^2 t + t^2}
{1+ \sin^2 t + t^2}
{1 + 2 t^2}
\cdot \vvvec{-2\cos t \sin t}{2\cos t \sin t}{2t}\ud t =
Ende
```

by the command `sed -r 's/\\vvvec[[:space:]]*\{([^\}]*)\}[[:space:]]*\{([^\}]*)\}[[:space:]]*\{([^\}]*)\}/\\begin\{pmatrix\}\1\\\\\2\\\\\3\\end\{pmatrix\}/g' source` and hope to get the result

```
Test Text
= \int_0^{\pi}\begin{pmatrix}1+\cos^2 t + t^2\\1+ \sin^2 t + t^2\\1 + 2 t^2\end{pmatrix}
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-2\cos t \sin t\\2\cos t \sin t\\2t\end{pmatrix}\ud t =
Ende
```

I'm sorry - I can not see, why is is not working.
The string seems to be okay, as `echo "\vvvec{1}{2}{3}" | sed -r 's/\\vvvec[[:space:]]*\{([^\}]*)\}[[:space:]]*\{([^\}]*)\}[[:space:]]*\{([^\}]*)\}/\\begin\{pmatrix\}\1\\\\\2\\\\\3\\end\{pmatrix\}/g'
\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}` is working fine.
It stops working when inserting `\sin` for example in one component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is not needed within a character class, in fact it adds the backslash to the class. Because of this `\{([^\}]*)\}` won't match `{\cos t}`.

So, this seems to work:

```
sed -r 's/\\vvvec[[:space:]]*\{([^}]*)\}[[:space:]]*\{([^}]*)\}[[:space:]]*\{([^}]*)\}/\\begin\{pmatrix\}\1\\\\\2\\\\\3\\end\{pmatrix\}/g'
```

Comment: This is a nice explanation: Thanks. But now, only the second line of `source` gots converted - the first did not. I think `[:space:]` includes newline, doesn't it? From: isspace()
checks for white-space characters. In the "C" and "POSIX" locales, these are: space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'), horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v').

Comment: It does but sed processes each line individually by default. But you can get around it: http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/

Answer (score 0):

To handle backslash properly, you can:

- translate **`\`** to **`@`**

  ```
  $ tr '\\' '@' <input.txt
  ```
- run **`sed`** command(also use **`@`** as **`\`**)

  ```
  $ sed ... >output.txt
  ```
- translate **`@`** back to **`\`**

  ```
  $ tr '\\' '@' <output.txt
  ```
- at last, pipe all these commands